# Accumulate all values at every point in time by symbol

Tags: kdb

I have this table:

```
execs:([]time:til 12;sym:`a`b`c`a`c`c`c`b`b`a`b`c;leavesQty:(1000;900;1300;800;1200;900;600;800;400;300;200;100))
```

I have different syms and for each at some time a leavesQty. And now I want to extend the table this way that at every row I get the sum of all leavesQty entries by sym at this time.

So I would have to come up to these values for this example:

```
execs:([]time:til 12;sym:`a`b`c`a`c`c`c`b`b`a`b`c;leavesQty:(1000;900;1300;800;1200;900;600;800;400;300;200;100);accLeavesQty:(1000;1900;3200;3000;2900;2600;2300;2200;1800;1300;1100;600))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you want to get the deltas of the leaves Qunatity for each symbol so can see how the value changes over time. After that you just need to do a cumulative sum of the resulting column.

```
 q)update sums accLeavesQty from update accLeavesQty:deltas leavesQty by sym  from execs
time sym leavesQty accLeavesQty
-------------------------------
0    a   1000      1000        
1    b   900       1900        
2    c   1300      3200        
3    a   800       3000        
4    c   1200      2900        
5    c   900       2600        
6    c   600       2300        
7    b   800       2200        
8    b   400       1800        
9    a   300       1300        
10   b   200       1100        
11   c   100       600
```

Answer (score 6):

You add this column with a single update statement if you use fby:

```
q)update accLeavesQty:sums (deltas;leavesQty) fby sym from execs
time sym leavesQty accLeavesQty
-------------------------------
0    a   1000      1000
1    b   900       1900
2    c   1300      3200
3    a   800       3000
4    c   1200      2900
5    c   900       2600
6    c   600       2300
7    b   800       2200
8    b   400       1800
9    a   300       1300
10   b   200       1100
11   c   100       600
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a nice case for fby

```
q)update accLeavesQty:sums (deltas;leavesQty) fby sym from execs
time sym leavesQty accLeavesQty
-------------------------------
0    a   1000      1000
1    b   900       1900
2    c   1300      3200
3    a   800       3000
4    c   1200      2900
5    c   900       2600
6    c   600       2300
7    b   800       2200
8    b   400       1800
9    a   300       1300
10   b   200       1100
11   c   100       600
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method involves recursion:

```
update accLeavesQty:sum each @[;;:;]\[()!();sym;leavesQty] from execs
```

It keeps a running dictionary of the last accLeavesQty for each sym and then calculates the sum of each of them

```
q)update accLeavesQty:@[;;:;]\[()!();sym;leavesQty] from execs
time sym leavesQty accLeavesQty
---------------------------------------
0    a   1000      (,`a)!,1000
1    b   900       `a`b!1000 900
2    c   1300      `a`b`c!1000 900 1300
3    a   800       `a`b`c!800 900 1300
4    c   1200      `a`b`c!800 900 1200
5    c   900       `a`b`c!800 900 900
6    c   600       `a`b`c!800 900 600
7    b   800       `a`b`c!800 800 600
8    b   400       `a`b`c!800 400 600
9    a   300       `a`b`c!300 400 600
10   b   200       `a`b`c!300 200 600
11   c   100       `a`b`c!300 200 100
```